# App not showing after import new component in App JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

After I import a new component in `app.js` the app renders nothing on the browser and does not even get an error. The new component is `cart.js`. Also sharing the `modal.js` code because it's used in the cart component as a wrapper.
Also when I remove the Cart component from App JS, the app runs fine.

App JS:

```
    import Header from "./components/Layout/Header";
    import Meals from "./components/Meals/Meals";
    import Cart from "./components/Cart/Cart";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <Cart />
          <Header />
          <main>
            <Meals />
          </main>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

> 

Cart.js file:

```
import Modal from "../UI/Modal";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";

const Cart = (props) => {
  const cartItems = (
    <ul className={classes["cart-items"]}>
      {[
        {
          id: "c1",
          name: "Biryani",
          Amount: 2,
          price: 250,
        },
      ].map((item) => (
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Modal>
        {cartItems}
        <div className={classes.total}>
          <span>Total Amount</span>
          <span>200</span>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button className={classes["button--alt"]}>Close</button>
          <button className={classes.button}>Order</button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

> 

Modal.js is used as a portal for the Cart component and ID "overlays" is coming from the index.html used as a portal.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import classes from "./Modal.module.css";

const Backdrop = (props) => {
  return <div className={classes.backdrop}></div>;
};

const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
  <div className={classes.modal}>
    <div className={classes.content}>{props.children}</div>;
  </div>;
};

const portalEl = document.getElementById("overlays");

const Modal = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Backdrop />, portalEl)}
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <ModalOverlay>{props.childres}</ModalOverlay>,
        portalEl
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? React tends to be very generous with its error reporting so I'd be surprised if there isn't anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Please change name here and try again

```
import Meals from "./components/Meals/Meals";
import Meals from "./components/Cart/Cart";
```

@aliezaheer

Comment: Well thanks for the note but it's not working, it's changed to "Meals" accidentally when I tried to import againg

Comment: Can you public your code on codesanbox ? I think 
it will be easier for people to help

Answer (score 0):

My bad, after spending half of my day I have found that I didn't use `return()`  for the ModalOverlay function in Modal.js file and it was not throwing the error in the terminal.

Correction:

```
const ModalOverlay = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.modal}>
      <div className={classes.content}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```